# CSS styles do not work in the development environment

Tags: angular

i use Window10 , Angular development CSS styles do not work in the development environment  ,but mac can work.

Comment: i use ::ng-deep can choose  css selector

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, macOS is better for programming than windows. You'll be able to find a way to fix this exact issue but I recommend you download macOS on your device to make it easier and more efficient so you don't run into such problems in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).